# Lambda Expressions Mixed with Statements in C#

Tags: lambda, conditional-statements, expression, operator-keyword

I have a portion of code in which I must use a function with a parameter obtained via a lambda statement (to simplify, something along the lines of this):

```
Item.Move(Array.Exists(mainArray, arrayItem => 
(variable == secondArray[Array.IndexOf(mainArray, arrayItem)]))
? secondArray[Array.IndexOf(mainArray, arrayItem)
: new Vector2(-variable.X, variable.Y));
```

The issue, though, is that in the first operation of the conditional operator, arrayItem is underlined and the error is shown "The name 'arrayItem' does not exist in the current context", even though it is defined in the beginning of the lambda.

Therefore, I tried to add a statement into the lambda, to give an externally defined variable the value of arrayItem, and it brought with it numerous errors.

Is there any way to reference this variable from the lambda expression? I cannot figure out why it is not carried over in the conditional operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Array.Exists(mainArray, (arrayItem) =>
    {
        return variable == secondArray[Array.IndexOf(mainArray, arrayItem)];
    });
```